# Why is scanf not storing user input?

Tags: c, printing, floating-point, scanf

```
float a;
printf("Enter a floating point number:\n");
scanf("%f", &a);
printf("%f", &a);
```

I am trying to prompt the user for a number, which will be stored as a float, but when I run the code all that is printed out is 0.0000. Can anybody tell me why, and what I have to change for the number inputted to be printed here?

Comment: Because you don't use `&a` in the `printf()` — just `a`.

Comment: while printing why are you printing `&a` print only `a`. If you want to print the address then use `%p` instead of `%f`

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the address of `a`, so you won't get the correct answer. It should be `printf("%f", a);`

Answer (score 1):

The `&`-operator is only for `scanf` statments to store  at address.

Try `printf("%f", a);`